# Possible to speed up infinite scrolling?

Tags: entries, control-panel

In the control panel, on the entries index page, Craft uses ​infinite scrolling. However, when you scroll to the bottom, there's a slight delay while you wait for more entries to load.

Unfortunately, I'm in a situation where I have to scroll through *thousands* of entries. I'm cleaning up some imported data, and yesterday I managed to clean up entries from A - M. Today I need to pick up where I left off, and clean up entries from N - Z.

**Is there anything I can do to speed up the scrolling process?** (besides having a faster server)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could open up the console and paste this then scroll to the bottom once.

After that, this will keep scrolling to the `#footer` every time a response from the `getMoreElements` request comes in.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, options) {
  if (options.url.slice(-15) === "getMoreElements") {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#footer')[0].scrollIntoView(true)
    }, 10)
  }
})
```

Comment: I love it! Preload all entries while I go grab a snack. ;)

Comment: This is so hacky it's amazing. Thumbs up.

Comment: Oh my, that is going to be immensely useful. For those interested, I've formatted Bill's solution for a bookmarklet for convenience. Just create a bookmark and paste the code below as the URL. One-click access! `javascript:$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event,xhr,options){if(options.url.slice(-15)==="getMoreElements"){setTimeout(function (){$('#footer')[0].scrollIntoView(true)},10)}})`